# ASP Dynamically Add Form rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a basic form with user input. I am trying to add a control to allow the user to add more rows as they like. I cannot get the UI to update when the AddRow_Click executes

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Table ID="InputTable" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Description</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Location</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Name of Person Responsible</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>   

            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Desc" placeholder="Description" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Loc" placeholder="Location" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Nm" placeholder="Name of Person Responsible" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:Table>

    <asp:Button id="AddRow" Text="Add Row" OnClick="AddRow_Click" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button id="DltRow" Text="Delete Row" OnClick="DltRow_Click" runat="server" />
</form>
```

C# Code

```
   protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.Text = @"< asp:TextBox ID = 'Tag' placeholder = 'Dynamic Tag' runat = 'server' Width = '100%' ></ asp:TextBox >";
    InputTable.Rows.Add(row);

}
```

**EDIT**
I tried this but still is not correct

```
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
    cell1.Controls.Add(txtbx);
    this.InputTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: You can't create server controls inside the Text property of another server control like that.  You need to new up the asp TextBox in c# and add it to the controls collection of the cell.

Comment: I edited with the what you suggested but it still is not working

Comment: Does a post-back occur on the page?  Are you using AJAX?

Comment: Your original table contains a flaw. The table only contains a `TableHeaderRow`.  You need a `TableRow` around those `TableCell`s. It will help.

Comment: In your second code example, you forgot to add the cell to the row.